# Remove substring at the end of a string based on a list of strings to remove

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, substring

I have a list of strings

```py
x=['llc', 'corp', 'sa']
```

I need to filter at the end of a column in my dataframe containing strings:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(['Geeks corp', 'toto', 'tete coope', 'tete sa', 'tata corp', 'titi', 'tmtm'] , columns =['Names'])
```

as output I would like to. have:

```py
list = ['Geeks', 'toto', 'tete coope', 'tete', 'tata', 'titi', 'tmtm']
```

What are your suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with regex pattern - added `$` for match end of string, added `\s+` for match space before and joined `|` for regex `or`:

```
pat = '|'.join(f'\s+{y}$' for y in x)
df['Names'] = df['Names'].str.replace(pat, '')
print (df)
        Names
0       Geeks
1        toto
2  tete coope
3        tete
4        tata
5        titi
6        tmtm
```

Comment: Just a second question, if in my list of string I have more than one word, for example x=['llc sa', 'corp cor', 'sa se'], and I would like to look those words in the whole string, not only at the end, how can I do?

Comment: @Hector Simon Benavides then use `pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(y) for y in x)
df['Names'] = df['Names'].str.replace('('+ pat + ')', '').str.replace(' +', ' ')`, not tested, on phone only.

Answer (score 0):

this solution will work

```
    import pandas as pd
    x=['llc', 'corp', 'sa'] 
    df = pd.DataFrame(['Geeks corp', 'toto', 'tete coope', 'tete sa', 'tata corp', 'titi', 'tmtm'] , columns =['Names'])
    for i in x:
        df["Names"] = df["Names"].str.replace(i, " ")
```

Comment: Not testing end of string in your solution

Comment: I assumed names in the list won't have any spaces around them.